# Agile Web Development with Rails - ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and have started working my way through 'Agile Web Development with Rails: Fourth Edition'. I'm currently at the Cart Creation chapter. I've mostly copied the code from the book, however my database is called 'dvds' instead of 'products' (because I'm creating a DVD Store for a project).

I've reached the end of the chapter and when I run the functional tests, I'm getting the following error:

```
test_should_destroy_dvd(DvdsControllerTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: line_items.dvd_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "line_items" WHERE ("line_items".dvd_id = 980190962)
app/models/dvd.rb:26:in `ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item'
app/controllers/dvds_controller.rb:76:in `destroy'
test/functional/dvds_controller_test.rb:50:in `test_should_destroy_dvd'
test/functional/dvds_controller_test.rb:49:in `test_should_destroy_dvd'
```

Here's the code from the dvd.rb file that it's referencing:

```
has_many :line_items 
before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
...
private
  def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
if line_items.empty?
  return true
else
  errors.add(:base, 'Line Items present')
  return false
 end
end
```

The code from dvds_controller.rb:

```
def destroy
    @dvd = Dvd.find(params[:id])
    @dvd.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(dvds_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

And the code from dvds_controller_test.rb:

```
test "should destroy dvd" do
    assert_difference('Dvd.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, :id => @dvd.to_param
    end

    assert_redirected_to dvds_path
  end
```

Essentially, I don't understand the error and I'm looking for help so to make it go away! I'm guessing the problem is with "no such column: line_items.dvd_id" but I don't know how to amend it. I've melted my brain trying to figure it out, so any help at all would be much appreciated.

*Edit:*
This seems to be where the problem is, in create_line_items.rb:

```
class CreateLineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :line_items do |t|
      t.integer :product_id
      t.integer :cart_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :line_items
  end
end
```

Also, here's the scehma:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20111125123848) do

  create_table "carts", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "dvds", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.decimal  "price",       :precision => 8, :scale => 2
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "line_items", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "cart_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema looks ok I think, the migration is missing dvd_id. How did you end up with dvd_id in your schema? Do you have another migration that adds it?

It might be worth checking what's actually in the database:

```
sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3

sqlite3> .schema line_items
```

Check that line_items does actually have the dvd_id column

Comment: Ah, I tried rename_column to see would it fix the problem. (I've changed the above code back to it's original form for clarity)

So yeah you're right, my problem is that I have a product_id column instead of a dvd_id column. How can I fix this?

Comment: You'll need to create another migration which has the rename_column. Then re-run rake db:migrate

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you run rake db:migrate to create your database.

Comment: I just double checked it, and I did run the migration. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like Cat said, make sure you ran your migrations, but also note that you may have forgotten to change the column name in the migration.  My guess is that in the past it was product_id.  It would be helpful if you also posted the migrations related to LineItem and the current db/schema.rb.

Comment: You're on the money re: product_id. I've edited my original post with the migration and schema code above. How can I fix this? Many thank yous!